# Sagemaker Batch Transform entry point

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Before the AWS Sagemaker batch transform I need to do some transform. is it possible to have an custom script and associate as entry point to BatchTransformer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inference code and requirement.txt should be stored as part of model.gz while training.  They will be used in the batch transform!!

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Batch Transformations do their transformations using a Model. However, this model can also be a Serial Inference Pipeline model, which is basically two or more models, one running after the other

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-pipelines.html

So, your first model could be one that does some transformations, then the second model does your predictions

It depends on what kind of transformations you're hoping to do. If it's reasonably straightforward, then use the scikit-learn image

Comment: Thanks Neil . I'm using a tensorflow container. The model expects the data in the below format ..
  {
   "sex": np.array(Df.sex.values),        
   "age": np.array(Df.age.values),
   'marital_status':np.array(Df.marital_status.values)
  }   . How can I handle this in inference.py's input_handler?

Comment: @TempleJersey you need to override `input_fn()` (and possibly `predict_fn()`) so you can accept whatever values you want and convert them to the appropriate structure for the next model. I would recommend playing with it locally first (just executing the python) to make sure it works as you want